# File access control in linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, module, linux-kernel

I`m writing a module to control file access. I'm now trying to implement the prohibition of file opening. 
I've already tried are kernel module system open overload: http://pastebin.com/JWKbpFYT 
I've also tried system read overload: http://pastebin.com/psK8vX41
The problem in the first one is that I could restrict access to target file only in console (it didn't work in graphical interface, e.g. gedit).
The second one didn't work as the system stopped responding on running gedit with target file. 
How can I prohibit file opening without using SELinux?

```
asmlinkage int custom_open(const char __user *file_name, int flags, mode_t mod)
{
   printk("hook: open(\"%s\")", file_name);
   if (!strcmp(file_name, "test"))
       return -1;
   return original_open(file_name, flags, mod);
}

struct file *fget(unsigned int fd)
{
 struct file *file;
 struct files_struct *files = current->files;

 rcu_read_lock();
 file = fcheck_files(files, fd);
 if (file) {
         /* File object ref couldn't be taken */
         if (file->f_mode & FMODE_PATH ||
             !atomic_long_inc_not_zero(&file->f_count))
                 file = NULL;
 }
 rcu_read_unlock();

 return file;
```

}

```
asmlinkage int custom_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t noct)
{
   struct file *filp = fget(fd);
   unsigned char f_name[DNAME_INLINE_LEN];
   strcpy(f_name,filp->f_path.dentry->d_name.name);
   if (!strcmp(f_name, "_ttt.c")){
        printk("hook1: read fd=(%d: -> %s)\n",fd,f_name);
        return -1;
 }
 return original_read(fd, buf, noct);
}
```

Comment: You can post code directly on SO. Please do it, I cannot open the links.

Comment: @teseter123 post the code in the question body, click edit and add it, indent it with 4 spaces to make the system highlight it.

Comment: Are you sure it's wise to identify the file by the user-submitted filename? What if the user `open()`s `./test` instead of `test`?

Comment: stupid error...
while opening with gedit, filename = path/to/filename.